# Start Timer from Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, timer

The Timer is defined like this:

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" runat="server" Interval="1000" Enabled="false" />
```

When calling `$find("<%= Timer1.ClientID %>")._startTimer();` I'm getting this error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property '_startTimer': object is null or undefined

and when calling `$('#Timer1')._startTimer();` I'm getting this error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method '_startTimer'

Any advice will be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing [`$find()`](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/ClientReference/Global/FindShortcutMethod.aspx) the shorter server-side (or "Component") ID:

```
$find("Timer1")._startTimer();
```

You may also be able to use [`$get()`](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/ClientReference/Global/GetShortCutMethod.aspx) with the `ClientID`:

```
$get("<%= Timer1.ClientID %>")._startTimer();
```

With jQuery, pass it the `ClientID` as with `$get()` and use [`.get(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to retrieve the DOM Object from the jQuery collection:

```
$('#<%= Timer1.ClientID %>').get(0)._startTimer();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works great now. Which method is preferred? By the way, is there a way to just invoke the `Tick` event without starting the timer?

Comment: @toy4fun Each method is a viable option. Just use the one that seems best to you. As for raising the `Tick` event, the control is [defined with a `_raiseTick` method](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1014bf767f65#Client%2fMicrosoftAjax%2fExtensions%2fSys%2fUI%2fControls%2fTimer.js), which `_startTimer` calls with a `setTimeout`.

Comment: If I understood correctly, I can call `_raiseTick` without enabling the timer?

Comment: @toy4fun For that, you'll want to call `_stopTimer` after `_raiseTick`, as `_raiseTick` calls `_startTimer` itself to setup the next `Tick`.

Comment: So now my code looks like that: `$find("Timer1")._raiseTick(); $find("Timer1")._stopTimer();`. Thanks Again.